# Java Code generation from XSD/WSDL for Jakarta 4.0.0 using Maven Plugin

Tags: xml, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin, jaxws-maven-plugin

I have wasted mutiple days trying to figure it out, how can something that seems pretty straightforward (generating code from a WSDL/XSD) be so extremly complicated. Are there any approaches? I feel I have tried them all, in diffrent versions using diffrent jaxb bindings and implementations in their diffrent versions

I tried using the following plugins:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

No plugin is able to output jakarta Annotations and always failes bc some javax.xml Annotiation or com.sun.* Class is missing. At this point I am thinking about writing a plugin myself, because this is ridiculous, I just need a simple POJO with some annotations and dont want to write them myself when the xsd or wsdl changes.

Are there any approaches you guys used that work for Jakarta 4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        *
    </parent>

    <artifactId>*</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <service.package>com.company</service.package>

        <jakarta.xml.ws-api.version>4.0.0</jakarta.xml.ws-api.version>
        <jaxws-rt.version>4.0.0</jaxws-rt.version>
        <jaxws-ri.version>4.0.0</jaxws-ri.version>
        <jaxws-maven-plugin.version>3.0.0</jaxws-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakarta.xml.ws-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxws-rt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxws-ri.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>USER_INFO</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>user_info.xml.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <packageName>${service.package}.userinfo</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

All dependencies now are jakarta.xml instead of javax.xml.

Comment: How can I generate setter methods for collection type parameters with the above code. I was using org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:1.11.1 with org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin before migrating from javax to jakarta, but this does not seem to work with com.sun.xml.ws plugin

Comment: Works like a charm, actually generates weird setter for collections (like any other xml ws plugin)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old but for reference the following plugin has been updated this year with many changes :

```xml
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
```

The repository URL has been updated : https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools

It now contains all the `org.jvnet.jaxb` related tools, including the maven-plugin and the jaxb2-basics xjc-plugins

You can follow the [migration guide](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB-Tools-Migration-Guide) in order to upgrade from 0.x versions to 2.x version (JAXB 2.3 `javax`), 3.x version (JAXB 3 `jakarta`) or 4.x version (JAXB 4 `jakarta`, jdk11)

For example, the plugin in v4 is now located at

```xml
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

and the `jaxb2-basics` are now here for generation :

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-plugins</artifactId>
```

and for `jaxb-plugins` runtime dependency :

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-plugins-runtime</artifactId>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [jaxws-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-maven-plugin) for generation of code from WSDL and [jaxb-maven-plugin](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb/jaxb-maven-plugin) for generating code from XSD.
Here is the config I've used:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <file>FiverxLinkService_01_10.wsdl</file>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>de.meona.ataxe.fiverx.wsdl</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Succesfully got java classes with imports from jakarta packages.