# Web service on Wildfly27 with jakarta.jakartaee-api10 . Successful deployment but can't get junit test to run successfully

Tags: maven, web-services, jakarta-ee, junit, wildfly

I successfully deployed a Web Service on Wildfly 27 with jakarta.jakartaee-api 10.0.0.
But I just can't get a junit test to access the web service.
I can call the wsdl via the browser and already tried all kinds of package imports to get the client to run, but I'm always getting package errors.
Have already read numerous posts and tried out the suggested package imports but all fails.

This is the wildfly console after deployment

```
 address=http://localhost:8080/ejb-server-basic-jaxws/AccountWS
 implementor=cs.edu.appserver.jaxws.AccountWS
 serviceName={http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/}AccountWSService
 portName={http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/}AccountWSPort
 annotationWsdlLocation=null
 wsdlLocationOverride=null
 mtomEnabled=false
 publishedEndpointUrl=http://localhost:8080/ejb-server-basic-jaxws/AccountWS
```

this is the wsdl

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="AccountWSService" targetNamespace="http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="account" type="tns:account"/>
<xs:element name="deposit" type="tns:deposit"/>
<xs:element name="depositResponse" type="tns:depositResponse"/>
<xs:element name="findAccountByName" type="tns:findAccountByName"/>
<xs:element name="findAccountByNameResponse" type="tns:findAccountByNameResponse"/>
<xs:element name="newAccount" type="tns:newAccount"/>
<xs:element name="newAccountResponse" type="tns:newAccountResponse"/>
<xs:element name="withdraw" type="tns:withdraw"/>
<xs:element name="withdrawResponse" type="tns:withdrawResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="withdraw">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="withdrawResponse">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="deposit">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="arg1" type="xs:long"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="depositResponse">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="findAccountByName">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="findAccountByNameResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:account"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="account">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="amount" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="newAccount">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="newAccountResponse">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="findAccountByNameResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:findAccountByNameResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="depositResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:depositResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="findAccountByName">
<wsdl:part element="tns:findAccountByName" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="withdrawResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:withdrawResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="withdraw">
<wsdl:part element="tns:withdraw" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="deposit">
<wsdl:part element="tns:deposit" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="newAccountResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:newAccountResponse" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="newAccount">
<wsdl:part element="tns:newAccount" name="parameters"> </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="AccountWSItf">
<wsdl:operation name="withdraw">
<wsdl:input message="tns:withdraw" name="withdraw"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:withdrawResponse" name="withdrawResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="deposit">
<wsdl:input message="tns:deposit" name="deposit"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:depositResponse" name="depositResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="findAccountByName">
<wsdl:input message="tns:findAccountByName" name="findAccountByName"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:findAccountByNameResponse" name="findAccountByNameResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="newAccount">
<wsdl:input message="tns:newAccount" name="newAccount"> </wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:newAccountResponse" name="newAccountResponse"> </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="AccountWSServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:AccountWSItf">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="withdraw">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="withdraw">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="withdrawResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="deposit">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="deposit">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="depositResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="findAccountByName">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="findAccountByName">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="findAccountByNameResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="newAccount">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="newAccount">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="newAccountResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AccountWSService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:AccountWSServiceSoapBinding" name="AccountWSPort">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ejb-server-basic-jaxws/AccountWS"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

this is my current pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cs.edu.appserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-server-basic-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.server.bom>21.0.1.Final</version.server.bom>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <jakartaee.version>10.0.0</jakartaee.version>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <apache.log4j2.version>2.20.0</apache.log4j2.version>
        <junit.version>5.3.1</junit.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <version.wildfly>26.1.1.Final</version.wildfly>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>${version.wildfly}</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakartaee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                    <add-user>
                        <users>
                            <user>
                                <username>xxxx</username>
                                <password>yyyy</password>
                            </user>
                        </users>
                    </add-user>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

this is my junit test

```
    public void testWebService() {
        String name = "John Smith";
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/ejb-server-basic-jaxws/AccountWS?wsdl");
            QName qname = new QName("http://jaxws.appserver.edu.cs/", "AccountWSService");
            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
            
            AccountWSItf ws = service.getPort(AccountWSItf.class);
            ws.newAccount(name);
            System.out.println("Created account name " + name);
            ws.deposit(name, 1000);
            System.out.println("Deposit $ 1000 ");
            ws.withdraw(name, 500);
            System.out.println("Withdraw $ 500 ");
            Account account = ws.findAccountByName(name);
            assertNotNull(account);
            long money = account.getAmount();
            assertEquals(500l, money);
            System.out.println("Account balance is " + account.getAmount());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
```

and this is the console when I run the test

```
com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: Eine WebService-Annotation ist in Klasse nicht vorhanden: cs.edu.appserver.jaxws.AccountWSItf
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1581)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getPortTypeName(RuntimeModeler.java:1572)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:449)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:210)
    at cs.edu.appserver.jaxws.test.ServiceTest.testWebService(ServiceTest.java:60)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
Exception: com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: Eine WebService-Annotation ist in Klasse nicht vorhanden: cs.edu.appserver.jaxws.AccountWSItf
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

the line

```
Eine WebService-Annotation ist in Klasse nicht vorhanden: cs.edu.appserver.jaxws.AccountWSItf
```

says that there is no web service annotation in class AccountWSItf

this is the interface AccountWSItf

```
import jakarta.jws.WebMethod;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public interface AccountWSItf {
    @WebMethod
    public void newAccount( String name);

    @WebMethod
    public void withdraw(String name, long amount) throws RuntimeException;

    @WebMethod
    public void deposit(String name, long amount);

    @WebMethod
    public Account findAccountByName(String name);
}
```

this is its implementation

```
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.jws.WebParam;
import jakarta.jws.WebResult;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;



@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style= SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class AccountWS implements AccountWSItf{
    @Inject
    AccountManager ejb;

 
    public void newAccount(@WebParam(name = "name") String name) {
        ejb.createAccount(name);

    }

 
    public void withdraw(@WebParam(name = "name") String name,
            @WebParam(name = "amount") long amount) throws RuntimeException {
        ejb.withdraw(name, amount);
    }

 
    public void deposit(@WebParam(name = "name") String name,
            @WebParam(name = "amount") long amount) {
        ejb.deposit(name, amount);
    }

    @WebResult(name = "BankAccount")
    public Account findAccountByName(String name) {
        return ejb.findAccount(name);
    }
}
```

followed numerous tutorials and posts on stackoverflow but just can't get the junit test to run.

Comment: this is the wsdl without the browser's style error message .... obviously can't post it here. 
but the wsdl has an xml tag

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing JakartaEE 10 and JavaEE 8 so it won't work: AccountWSItf is JakartaEE 10 annotated while your client code is loking for 'old' javax annotation. You need to be coherent in your code

Comment: Thank you very much :) ... I gathered the code from different examples.

Comment: I updated the imports ... that was really stupid :) 
I got maven to create the client classes but there again of course, javax imports instead of jakarta.
Does anyone know a wsimport plugin to generate jakarta based client classes out of eclipse? 
I'm currently using jaxws-maven-plugin2.6 but there the service is always null. I'm assuming beause it as well is javax-based

Comment: this post contains the maven plugin to generate jakarta client sources. 
```
<groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0</version>
```
taken from
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611835/java-code-generation-from-xsd-wsdl-for-jakarta-4-0-0-using-maven-plugin[/link]
still the service remains null when invoking it in junit like this: 
```
 @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation =
        "http://localhost:8080/ejb-server-basic-jaxws/AccountWS?wsdl")
 private static AccountWSService service;
```
the url to the swdl is correct

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the dependency versions that work together.

properties of the pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
    <maven.compiler.source.version>11</maven.compiler.source.version>
    <maven.compiler.target.version>11</maven.compiler.target.version>
    <jakartaee.version>10.0.0</jakartaee.version>
    <jaxws-maven-plugin.version>3.0.2</jaxws-maven-plugin.version>
    <junit.version>5.3.1</junit.version>
    <apache.log4j2.version>2.20.0</apache.log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

jax-ws plugin to create the client stubs

```
        <!-- jax-ws maven plugin use with maven build:  jaxws:wsimport  -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>
                        http://localhost:8080/jakarta-soap-with-client-1.0.0/CountryServiceImpl?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <packageName>cs.edu.jakarta.soap.client</packageName>
                <destDir>src/main/java/cs/edu/jakarta/soap/client</destDir>
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and the dependencies to run the unit tests

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>
            com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>
            com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

the maven build is then

```
clean install jaxws:wsimport
```

In my junit test I can then init the service

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setup() {
    try {
        service = new CountryServiceImplService();
        countryService = service.getCountryServiceImplPort();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```